# VBA FileDialog.Show restarts sub

Tags: vba, excel, show, filedialog

I'm trying to get the path for a folder using the `filedialog.show` function.

The issue I am facing is:

- After I select a folder in the folderpicking window the code does not continue. It either restarts or it ends without anything happening.

What could be the problem?

```
[...]

Dim fpath As Variant
Dim fldr As Object
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
fldr.Title = "Select a Folder"
fldr.AllowMultiSelect = False
fldr.InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
If fldr.Show = -1 Then
    fpath = fldr.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    GoTo NextCode
End If
NextCode: 
set fldr = Nothing

[...]
```

Comment: Code works for me.  The fault probably lies with the section you have shown as `[...]`, which makes it a bit hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It works, you are just not using it to display the path result (or return a `String` value from this `Sub`).

Change your code:

```
If fldr.Show = -1 Then
    fpath = fldr.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    GoTo NextCode
End If

NextCode: 
set fldr = Nothing
```

To:

```
If fldr.Show = -1 Then
    fpath = fldr.SelectedItems(1)
    MsgBox fpath ' <-- for DEBUG
End If

Set fldr = Nothing
```

---

If you want to use your code as a `Function` that returns the path of the selected folder, use the code below:

```
Function GetFolderPath() As String

Dim fpath As Variant
Dim fldr As Object

Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath

    If .Show = -1 Then
        GetFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With    
Set fldr = Nothing

End Function
```

And the `Sub` code to test it:

```
Sub Test()

Dim FolderPath As String

FolderPath = GetFolderPath
MsgBox FolderPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Apparently indeed the code works fine. It was just that I was using the debugging "step into " and it got lost. I used the MsgBox as checkpoint and a break line further in the code and everithing went smoothly.